# Combine or report on individual and household donations

Tags: contributions, households, donations, individual

So I have two issues that I am trying to overcome.

Like others, I have a need to aggregate donations up to the Household level in a quick and easy way.  Ultimately, it would be great if we could transfer donations already made to the household level but not sure that it is possible (I couldn't find a way to move donations entered to another account).

I have read the posts of Soft Credit and about the extension titled "AGGREGATE HOUSEHOLD CONTRIBUTIONS REPORT".

We are currently on version 5.25.0 so I am not clear of the extension mentioned will work for us or not.

Anyone with advice on this subject - please reply.

Thanks,

E

Answer (score 2):

hi and excuse the slight whinge but... providing links to things like the extension, makes it quicker for other busy folk (we all are) to help. And explaining 'why' you think it might not work also saves folk time looking stuff up.

[AGGREGATE HOUSEHOLD CONTRIBUTIONS REPORT](https://civicrm.org/extensions/aggregate-household-contributions-report) has its last release as 4.6. Best I can suggest is give it a spin and report back. That way if it works the maintainer of it may update the details

it can also be worth checking the git page and checking the [Issues](https://github.com/twomice/me.twomice.civicrm.aggregatehouseholdcontributions/issues) to see if anyone else is commenting about it working on more recent.

NOTE: if an extension says it is good for 4.7 then in theory it is good for 5.x

And Bingo! there is an issue about [4.7 compatability](https://github.com/twomice/me.twomice.civicrm.aggregatehouseholdcontributions/issues/7)

and

[image]

so chances are good to very good. and if you report back on that issue (it is easy to do so) then every chance Allen (twomice) will take the hint and update.

Better still if you are keen (and welcome to this diy community) submit a PR on the [info.xml](https://github.com/twomice/me.twomice.civicrm.aggregatehouseholdcontributions/blob/master/info.xml) and you will have made Allen's life at least one-click easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

To respond to the part of the question about moving a contribution, you can use the [Move Contributions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution) extension.